# Beep using buzzer just when battery died or 5V connection died using capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I have a small circuit where i am using Arduino PRO MINI to make a beep using buzzer at regular interval.

I am trying to make a beep when my 5V adapter loses power (electricity gone) or even if am attaching it to a battery which died.

I don't have a plan to use extra battery for the same nor i know how to use it as well.

Is it possible i can use capacitor say 1 Farad which when battery died will discharge and made a beep (2 small beep will be good for identification) for a second and then everything is dead.

Some concerns were:

1. Is these cheap buzzers have any affect if it put them on opposite direction as they will beep on discharge of capacitor
2. Does they get impacted if the electricity comes back while it is being discharged
3. The capacitors does not charge linear i.e their voltage drops will that be too bad for my buzzer

I really don't want to try something as it can burn my ICs etc.

Comment: use the normal battery to hold a relay open so when it fails the relay closes and starts the buzzer

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible i can use capacitor say 1 Farad which when battery died will discharge and made a beep (2 small beep will be good for identification) for a second and then everything is dead.

Yes it is possible.

You won't need a whole 1 Farad. [This buzzer](https://www.pololu.com/product/1260) for example says 1V-30V and 5mA at 9V. If we guess that it can go down to 1V, from 5V, over 1 second, using 5mA, then the capacitance you need is:

$$C = \frac{Q}{dV} =\frac{5mA\cdot1s}{4V} = 1.25 mF$$

> Some concerns were:
>
> 1. Is these cheap buzzers have any affect if it put them on opposite direction

I would not make current go the wrong way through a buzzer. It might work for your buzzer, or it might not. Maybe they make buzzers where it works. I wouldn't try it, unless I can replace the buzzer if it breaks.

You can use diodes so that current only goes the right way through the buzzer.

Or, since you have an Arduino already, why don't you make it so the Arduino is powered by the capacitor and the Arduino has an input which tells it when the power is lost?

> 2. Does they get impacted if the electricity comes back while it is being discharged

See above.

> 3. The capacitors does not charge linear i.e their voltage drops will that be too bad for my buzzer

It depends. You will not break the buzzer if the voltage is too low, but the sound might be wrong.

Comment: great explaination, thank you, i will try my evening. So should i just add this capacitor in parallel to a battery/power source right?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a microcontroller, there's a common way to achieve the result without adding much extra to what you already have.

Make sure your power supply has enough capacitance to run the Arduino for a short period when power is lost.  That could be as little as a second if you just want a beep.

If your power supply has a "power fail" output, connect that to a GPIO pin, and beep the moment that pin changes state.

Otherwise, connect the power supply to an analog input.  Monitor the input regularly.  If the voltage drops below normal, emit a quick beep before the power fails completely.